# Getting HTTPRequest / HTTPResponse Header Size in Bytes

Tags: java, http, http-headers, size, httprequest

I'm sending an HTTPrequest to a Java Servlet and then having the servlet send back an HTTPResponse. What I want to do is to have the servlet grab the size of the headers in bytes. It's easy for me to get the size of the content but how would I go about getting the size of the headers both ways?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? I'm asking because if we knew the original problem, we might be able to suggest a way around this.

Answer (score 0):

The header is more like a dictionary (keys and values), its overall size isn't as important as the size of the body. But if you need to, you can always use [`getHeaders`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader%28java.lang.String%29) or the like.